# nHibernate - When to use objects when defining a class (and table)

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I recently dove headfirst into a project that uses nHibernate heavily. I've gotten a lot of the concepts down enough to implement them, but I'm having a hard time determining when to use objects related to tables in a class defining a different table.

This is just a very basic example I made up... I could create the Order class (which contains a FK to StateID) with standard types, but from what I've seen, I can also use existing objects in my definitions. For example, StateID could be:

```
    // StateID int, NOT NULL
    private int _stateid;
    public virtual int StateID
    {
        get { return this._stateid; }
        set { this._stateid= value; }
    }
```

or

```
    // State Object
    private State _state;
    public virtual State State
    {
        get { return this._state; }
        set { this._state= value; }
    }
```

Is an object only used if there is a relation that needs to cascade changes? When should I be using a standard type vs an object based on a table? It doesn't seem to make sense to use an object if I'm only using one property of the object (like the PK). Unless, of course, I need to easily access a different property. IE: I could do Order.State.StateName to get the name of the state associated with the StateID in the order table. Maybe this is when it's used?

I didn't word this as well as I would have liked, but I think it gets the general question out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define `lazy="proxy"` in the mapping of the property `State`:

```
<many-to-one name="State" class="State" lazy="proxy" ... />
```

If you do this, a proxy is created for the property `State` that only contains the Id. So as long as you only access `Order.State.Id`, it doesn't fetch the whole `State` object from the database. If you *do* access any other property of the `State` object, then NHiberate will automatically fetch the complete `State` object from the database.

Comment: So what would the difference between using lazy="proxy" and just saving it as an int containing the PK value of StateID be?

Comment: The difference is that you don't explicitly have to fetch State object yourself when you need it. Just write `Order.State.StateName` to get the name, and NHibernate will automatically fetch the information for you.

Comment: One more thing - does it make a difference whether or not I use an object when I want a change to propagate through children, or is that all based on the xml mapping and my cascade value?

Comment: If you have `default-lazy` turned on you don't have to specify explicitly that a related object is lazy loaded. http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-mapping in fact it's the best practice because NHibernate is built to be lazy